# How to Move a Doorway in a Load Bearing Wall?

Tags: walls, framing, interior, load-bearing

This is my first remodel attempt and I would like to create a doorway between a bedroom and a walk-in closet. The existing wall between the two rooms is a load-bearing wall. After removing the sheetrock, I see that the existing configuration is actually a remodel from a previous floor plan where a doorway used to be in almost the same place that I would like to place my doorway.

I would like the shift the doorway a foot or two to one side, however, I see that there is a concrete piece under the base plate (see picture below).

[image: Concrete under wall (left), 2x4 under previous door (right)]

What is this concrete piece and can it be removed?

Comment: we need to see the top of the wall and the whole wall to get a better understanding.

Comment: looks like a cinder block as part of the load bearing structure.

Comment: Yes, it is cinder block. Can it be removed without compromising the load bearing qualities of the wall?

Comment: Yes, it is cinder block. Can it be removed without compromising the load bearing qualities of the wall?